# Raspberry Pi 4 GPPUDCLK0, c++ assignment operator fails silently?

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi4

**Background:**
I'm trying to edit the GPPUDCLK0 register of the Raspberry Pi 4, I can read from the register but when I try to assign (1<<21) to it the assignment returns 0 instead and subsequent readings show that the register stays unchanged.

**Question:**
Is it possible for the c++ assignment operator to fail silently?

**Source**

```
int fdgpio = this->open_gpio_file();
        
if (fdgpio >= 0) 
{   
unsigned int *gpio=(unsigned int *)mmap( 0, 4096, PROT_READ+PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fdgpio, 0);
    
//write the updated register value to the register
//gpio[GPIO_Control::PI_4_GPPUD_INT_OFFSET] = command;
std::cout << "equal be: " << std::bitset<32>(gpio[GPIO_Control::PI_4_GPPUD_INT_OFFSET] = command) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Commands: " << std::bitset<32>(gpio[GPIO_Control::PI_4_GPPUD_INT_OFFSET]) << std::endl;

int wait_count = 0;//count through count_limit cycles
while(wait_count < wait_limit)
{
    wait_count += 1;
}

unsigned short bit_offset;
unsigned short clock_offset;

if(32 > gpio_number)
{
    bit_offset = gpio_number;
    clock_offset = GPIO_Control::PI_4_GPPUDCLK0_INT_OFFSET;
}

else
{
    bit_offset = gpio_number - 32;
    clock_offset = GPIO_Control::PI_4_GPPUDCLK1_INT_OFFSET;
}

std::cout << "Clk Offset: " << clock_offset << std::endl;

//activate the clock
uint32_t temp = (1<<bit_offset);
std::cout << "equal be: " << std::bitset<32>(gpio[clock_offset] = temp) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Should be: " << std::bitset<32>(temp) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Clk 0: " << std::bitset<32>(gpio[GPIO_Control::PI_4_GPPUDCLK0_INT_OFFSET]) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Clk 1: " << std::bitset<32>(gpio[GPIO_Control::PI_4_GPPUDCLK1_INT_OFFSET]) << std::endl;


wait_count = 0;//count through count_limit cycles
while(wait_count < wait_limit)
{
    wait_count += 1;
}

//clear both registers
gpio[GPIO_Control::PI_4_GPPUD_INT_OFFSET] = 0;
gpio[clock_offset] = 0;

std::cout << "Commands: " << std::bitset<32>(gpio[GPIO_Control::PI_4_GPPUD_INT_OFFSET]) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Clk 0: " << std::bitset<32>(gpio[GPIO_Control::PI_4_GPPUDCLK0_INT_OFFSET]) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Clk 1: " << std::bitset<32>(gpio[GPIO_Control::PI_4_GPPUDCLK1_INT_OFFSET]) << std::endl;
}
```

**Output**
from the two separate call for commands 01 and 10

```
equal be:    00000000000000000000000000000010
Commands:    00000000000000000000000000000010
Clk Offset: 24
equal be:    00000000000000000000000000000000
Should be:   00000000001000000000000000000000
Clk 0:       00000000000000000000000000000000
Clk 1:       00000000000000000000000000000000
Commands:    00000000000000000000000000000000
Clk 0:       00000000000000000000000000000000
Clk 1:       00000000000000000000000000000000


equal be:    00000000000000000000000000000001
Commands:    00000000000000000000000000000001
Clk Offset: 24
equal be:    00000000000000000000000000000000
Should be:   00000000001000000000000000000000
Clk 0:       00000000000000000000000000000000
Clk 1:       00000000000000000000000000000000
Commands:    00000000000000000000000000000000
Clk 0:       00000000000000000000000000000000
Clk 1:       00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: No. Provide your source code example for more info.

Comment: I know nothing about the Raspberry Pi GPPUDCLK0 register but I do know this for sure:  _Hardware registers are strange beasts_.  They work the way the hardware designer wanted them to work, and those guys don't care a fig about programmers, probably, they hate programmers and love to screw us up.  Regardless of the reason, _many hardware registers in real devices in real machines can only be read, not written or only be written, not read, and, if you can do both, there's no reason you should expect a read to read what you wrote!_ That's the way it is in general, maybe for GPPUDCLK0 too.

Comment: I believe there are special calls that you need to make on a Pi when you are using GPIOs, to specify whether they are in read- or write-mode.  They cannot be in both.

Comment: (IOW: Until you find docs that specifically say you can read GPPUDCLK0 and get what you last wrote into it, or better, _find actual code that does this and that really works_, don't assume you can read it just because you can write it.  Note that in [this page of documentation](https://github.com/s-matyukevich/raspberry-pi-os/blob/master/docs/lesson01/rpi-os.md) (not official) the only examples show it being _written_, not _read_.  Suggestion: read the [manual](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/files/1888662/BCM2837-ARM-Peripherals.-.Revised.-.V2-1.pdf) - it's the only authority.)

Comment: I've used a couple of other registers as read/write so I just assumed I could do the same here. I now see that was a leap in logic. 

Thanks for the help.